# How can a FB Messenger bot detect an end of conversation?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

We are developing a FB Messenger bot and would like to detect an end of conversation event.

We would ideally like to get a callback event when the user leaves the conversation by explicitly closing the chat window.   We are currently just using an idle timer if we have not heard from the user in a while to decide if the user is no longer interested in continuing the conversation. We also provide a persistent menu option to end the session but most users will possibly not use it. (We do realize that on mobile devices users may not be in the habit of explictly closing the chat window but just switching away from the chat window in which case infocus/out of focus events may be useful if available).

How does one achieve this goal with the FB Messenger API?

Comment: As far as I know, this kind of event doesn't (yet?) exist in FB Messenger API. And this is sad.